# How to set the preferredContentSize of a UIViewController to the height of a containing UITableView contentSize?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I call a popover like the following:

```
if let vc = CalendarDetailViewControllerContainer.storyboardInstance() {
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: ((self.view.frame.width / 5) * 2), height: vc.view.frame.height);
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover;
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self;
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.any;
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView;
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sourceView.frame.size.width, height: sourceView.frame.size.height);

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

As you can see for now I set the `preferredContentSize` height to `vc.view.frame.height`. But that should be different. For now, more code. In the following my `CalendarDetailViewControllerContainer`:

```
class CalendarDetailViewControllerContainer : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!;

    static func storyboardInstance() -> CalendarDetailViewControllerContainer? {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: NSStringFromClass(CalendarDetailViewControllerContainer.classForCoder()).components(separatedBy: ".").last!), bundle: nil);

        return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? CalendarDetailViewControllerContainer;
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        self.setupView();
        self.setupDetailView();
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
        self.view.isOpaque = false;
    }

    func setupDetailView() {
        if let vc = CalendarDetailViewController.storyboardInstance() {
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc);

            self.addChildViewController(navigationController);

            navigationController.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;

            self.containerView.addSubview(navigationController.view);

            navigationController.didMove(toParentViewController: self);
        }
    }
}
```

I need this container because for later purposes and future segues I will need the navigation controller (and I wont build it in storyboard). So the last part of the code:

```
class CalendarDetailViewController : UITableViewController {

    static func storyboardInstance() -> CalendarDetailViewController? {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: NSStringFromClass(CalendarDetailViewController.classForCoder()).components(separatedBy: ".").last!), bundle: nil);

        return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? CalendarDetailViewController;
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true;

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
}
```

What I now try to do is to set the `preferredContentSize` height of the popover to be exactly the `contentSize` of the table view.

How can I do that?

Comment: In Swift you can omit all semicolon at the end of the line;

Comment: Hi. I know that. But for me it is very bad coding style to not use semicolons ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can override preferredContentSize for CalendarDetailViewControllerContainer, but make sure that you reloaded table and calling `layoutIfNeeded()` before calculating the size.

```
public override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        return CGSize(width: tableView.contentSize.width,
                      height: tableView.contentSize.height + tableView.layoutMargins.top + tableView.layoutMargins.bottom)
    }

    set { super.preferredContentSize = newValue }
}
```